# not completed image after decoding it php Android

Tags: php

PHP:

```
<?php
require "conn.php";
$cid = "6";// $_POST["cid"];
$mysql_qry = "select image2 from cities where ID = '$cid'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$mysql_qry);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

header('Content-Type: image/png');
echo base64_decode($row["image2"]);
$conn->close();
?>
```

and this is the result

[image]

How to solve that? my photo is almost black!

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: What column type/length is `image2`? Are you certain the whole image is being saved?

Comment: @NicoHaase The rest of the image. the black part was an image before decoding it :(

Comment: @iainn  varchar(5000) .... I don't know.. In andriod part i encode it from bitmap to byteArray to base46 and save it in the database

Comment: 5000 characters for a base64 encoded image doesn't sound like very much

Comment: @iainn What should it be ??

Comment: Only you can answer that. Base-64 encode your image, and see how long the string is before saving it to the database. Your column needs to be *at least* that size.

Comment: So, why did you use `varchar` after all? Why not use a `blob` field?

Comment: @NicoHaase I don't know whats is blob !

Comment: @Nico Haasse I tried it, And it works
Thank you.  ^_^

Answer (score 0):

- As i can see you are collecting image source from the database table. You must check that weather your entire image source is saved properly after encoding it. So check the database Column Data Type in which you have stored it i doubt that its not saving the full image source hence further you are not able to get the full image.

Advice : Most probably Best Practice is that you should convert it to image and save it on disk and just save the IMAGE SOURCE PATH on your Database Table Column. And then fetch it to display when required.
Otherwise Your DB will exausted and will start taking time in retrieving the records. Also problem will start in DB Backup and migrations.

If you dont want to follow the advise then change your column type to Either Blob depending on your image size.